# NSNumber numberWithFloat vs Init and alloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this line of code and am trying to figure out the pros and cons of the way I wrote it.  I am just trying to set a label to a float value and both work.... just don't know which is better...

```
self.display.text=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:32.445] stringValue];
```

Is there any difference to say

```
NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithFloat:32.445];
self.display.text = [number stringValue];
```

Well - I know there must be a difference - just not sure what it would be.  Seems like the first is more of a wrapper (if that makes sense)?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:32.445]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:32.445] autorelease]
```

in Manual Reference counting mode. In ARC or GC mode, you can consider it equivalent to:

```
[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:32.445]
```

Only benefit you might likely get is to try to avoid the `autorelease` call in MRC mode and replace it with a `release` call.

Comment: They can actually behave quite differently in practice — at least on 32-bit targets. I just ran a test with Xcode 7.2.1 and found that `+numberWithFloat` and `@(n)` both allocate objects in that have to be autoreleased later, which, if you're in a big loop creating lots of these, can waste tons of memory (about 20 bytes per `unsigned long long int`). In contrast, `+alloc`/`+init` causes the object to be destroyed immediately after its last use. Oddly, on a 64-bit target, neither of these three alternatives gobble up memory. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Of course, if you are in a loop, the auto release will kill you as for any objects. Performance and memory wise. In 64bit, Foundation uses tagged pointer (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer) as much as it can for NSNumbers to avoid allocations/deallocations.

Answer (score 2):

> Seems like the first is more of a wrapper (if that makes sense)?

That is *exactly* what it is in the majority of implementations, and barring corner cases =p It's called a convenience constructor.

As far as which you should prefer - whatever's clearer to you. I prefer `alloc`+`init` because it's easier to manage memory and requires slightly less overhead (apart from corner cases).

If you know you have a lot of objects to make or are writing performance/memory critical code (*cough* iOS devices), then you should consider favoring alloc+init for your 'heavier' code.

Answer (score 1):

The `numberWithFloat:` selector calls a class method on NSNumber (much like a static method from Java, C#, or C++). The `initWithFloat:` selector calls an instance method on a specific NSNumber object. You use `[NSNumber alloc]` to get the instance to init.

(See [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more.)

It's definitely fair to think of the static method as a wrapper for the second form, because somebody somewhere must be calling `alloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running under ARC, you need to [number release] in the latter case.  For a one-off use, then, the former case - using +numberWithFloat: - is probably preferable (less typing = fewer bugs, clearer code).

The only real difference I can think of is that if you are using these in certain performance-critical applications, especially where loops are involved, there are more complex memory optimization considerations when deciding whether to use class or instance methods.  These however don't really apply here (presumably this is UI code), so just make your life simple and use +numberWithFloat:.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html), then I suppose both ways are the same.

If you're working without ARC, like most of obj-c developers have been through, then your second snippet leaks memory, you may consider writing like this:

```
NSNumber *number = [[[NSNumber alloc]initWithFloat:32.445] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the alloc/initWithFloat method, I believe 'number' will have to be released somewhere.